# Diskpart clean/ reboot and select proper boot device

Tags: desktop-computer

I was doing a reset on my pc and half-way through I got a black screen. So I went into bios and tried to find a way to wipe the drives thinking it would start back to factory setting and I had my usb with windows 10 on it, to boot windows up when all else failed. So I went online and found a command prompt where you type in "diskpart" or "view all disk"  and I cleaned all the disk I had which was 0,1,2. While my usb was in the pc. So when I reset my pc to boot up windows through my usb it just says "reboot and select proper boot device or insert proper boot media in selected boot device and press key" and it says this when ever I try to boot it up anything. I'm kinda new to this and I just need help

Answer (score 0):

You can you a Windows DVD (or USB) and try to repair the installation. Maybe search for [bcdedit](https://neosmart.net/wiki/bcdedit/) online.

The other possibility (to at least backup your data) is to run something like a [Ubuntu Live-DVD](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) (or USB), which is a full operating system, that you can use to copy data without installing it to your hard disk. It will run a bit slow from the DVD or USB, be patient.

Comment: It's weird no matter what I try to boot up. Even with a usb containing windows 10 iso. And it still tells me "reboot and select proper boot device" I don't know what to do I feel like I've tried everything

Comment: Really, try the Ubuntu way, that way You can at least save your data (like copy them to a USB hard disk or something). If you have the capacity, You can actually save a copy of the C: partition using dd so You can browse it later in case You missed something. Let me know, if this is interesting for You.
After that, you will probably have to reinstall - I know, that is very inconvenient. While You are at it, consider upgrading to an SSD, if You haven't one already.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm not concerned about saving the data, I was trying to boot windows 10 one the pc using a usb iso file. I made the usb first to boot, but the message keeps popping up "reboot and select proper boot device